# scope variable not updating with ng-change - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Seems like a simple problem though but finding it hard to fix. 
There is a pagination component, that has a button & a dropdown. User can go to a page by either clicking the button or selecting that page number in dropdown.

The problem is, when I select a value in the dropdown, nothing happens. Because the scope variable doesnt change from the previous one.

**aspx:**

```
<div data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="ReportsCtrl">
<div id="paging-top">                
 <div>
   <ul>         
     <li>
       <select data-ng-model="SelectedPage" data-ng-change="ShowSelectedPage();" 
        data-ng-options="num for num in PageNumbers track by num">
       </select>
     </li>
     <li data-ng-click="ShowNextPage();"><a href="#">Next</a></li>         
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);
```

**ReportsCtrl.js**

```
app.controller("ReportsCtrl", ["$scope","ReportsFactory",function ($scope,ReportsFactory) {

init();
var init = function () { 
  $scope.ShowReport(1);
}

$scope.ShowReport = function (pageNumber) {
  GetUserResponsesReport(pageNumber);
} 

function GetUserResponsesReport(pageNumber) {

    $scope.UserResponsesReport = [];        
    var promise = ReportsFactory.GetReport();
    promise.then(function (success) {
        if (success.data != null && success.data != '') {                
            $scope.UserResponsesReport = success.data;                
            BindPageNumbers(50, pageNumber);
        }            
    });        
}

function BindPageNumbers(totalRows, selectedPage) {        
    $scope.PageNumbers = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++) {
        $scope.PageNumbers.push(i);
    }
    $scope.SelectedPage = selectedPage;        
}

$scope.ShowSelectedPage = function () {
    alert($scope.SelectedPage);
    $scope.ShowReport($scope.SelectedPage);
}

 $scope.ShowNextPage = function () {        
    $scope.SelectedPage = $scope.SelectedPage + 1;
    $scope.ShowReport($scope.SelectedPage);        
}   
}]);
```

Say, the selected value in dropdown is 1. When I select 2 in the dropdown, the alert shows1. When `Next` is clicked, the dropdown selection changes to 2 as expected. Now, when I select 1 in the dropdown, the alert shows 2.

Tried to make a fiddle, but do not know how to do with a `promise` - http://jsfiddle.net/bpq5wxex/2/

Comment: how many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: sorry about that. Posting the entire code was making the post lengthy and new edits weren't attracting any responses after a certain period. Been fighting with this issue for long. Hence tried creating a simpler/almost complete code again.Thanks for your help.

Comment: I do not understand why the `$scope.SelectedPage` wasnt updating with `ng-change`, but this little hack worked. - sending the value as parameter

Comment: `data-ng-change="ShowSelectedPage(SelectedPage);` and in controller - `$scope.ShowSelectedPage = function (val) {$scope.SelectedPage=val;}`

Comment: well, if the answer to this question is actually the key to the solution, then I suspect that you are falling in the trap of JavaScript Prototype Inheritance.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your OP  **SelectedPage** is just **primitive variable**.

**With every angular directive new scope is get created.**

So,**SelectedPage** is not update outside the **ng-repeat** scope after drop-down is changed i.e. in parent scope which is your controller.
In order to do this,use **Object variable** instead of primitive data types as it update the value by reference having same memory location.

Try to define **SelectedPage** object in controller in this way.

```
$scope.objSelectedPage = {SelectedPage:''};
```

in HTML

```
<select data-ng-model="objSelectedPage.SelectedPage" data-ng-change="ShowSelectedPage();"
```

In **ShowSelectedPage**

```
 $scope.ShowSelectedPage = function () {

    console.log($scope.objSelectedPage.SelectedPage);
    $scope.ShowReport($scope.objSelectedPage.SelectedPage);

}
```

Comment: What a great insight! Thanks!